# Cannot access phpMyAdmin via localhost/phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image]

I have aproblem with phpMyAdmin, I cannot access it via this link http://localhost/phpmyadmin/.

It just asked password and does nothing and there is no error message appear.
I tried to remove it and reinstall but there is no change. When I open it from Firefox browser this message appears:

> Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

It only opens on Chrome but not working as I cleared above.

Comment: Take a look at /var/log/php.. and on your term : tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking 
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini  and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
if session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5" update it to 
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5/session" and un comment it , restart apache then it works.